# facebook login redirection is not working

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication

i'm trying to use facebook login to fetch users data the mail url is like this http://www.mawk3y.net/news2/news_details.php?id=34 (you can test it yourself) just scroll down and you'll see a button : login with facebook it takes you to another page fb.php with this code

```
  <?php
$referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
?>
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/registration?client_id=id here&redirect_uri=<?php echo $referrer; ?>&source=fb&fields=name,birthday,gender,location,email,first_name,last_name"
    scrolling="auto"
    frameborder="no"
    style="border:none"
    allowTransparency="true"
    width="100%"
    height="530">
</iframe>
```

the problem is the url redirect is not working it takes me back to the referrer page without the query string "source=fb"

Comment: That’s most likely because you neglected to URL-encode the parameter value properly.

Comment: And btw., how unreliable the HTTP referer is, you’re hopefully aware of …?

Answer (score 0):

Use `urlencode($url)` when you echo the urls.

Comment: you mean like this: redirect_uri=<?php echo urlencode($url); ?>&source=fb&

Comment: Yes. You need to urlencode the url to work properly with redirection.

Comment: it doesn't work and you can check http://www.mawk3y.net/news2/news_details.php?id=7
final code:
<?php
  $url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
  ?>
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/registration?client_id=331805196916042&redirect_uri=<?php echo urlencode($url); ?>&source=fb&fields=name,birthday,gender,location,email,first_name,last_name"
        scrolling="auto"
        frameborder="no"
        style="border:none"
        allowTransparency="true"
        width="100%"
        height="530">
</iframe>